# How come method returning boolean still compiles when return uses a ternary operator?

Tags: java

How come this code compiles? I would have expected the compiler to complain about a "Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to boolean" but it doesn't. It just fails with a NullPointerException at runtime.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("this throws a NPE: " + whyIsThisPossible(1, 2));
}

private static boolean whyIsThisPossible(int a, int b) {
    return a + b == 2 ? true : null;
}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at FunkyMethodTest.whyIsThisPossible(FunkyMethodTest.java:10)
at FunkyMethodTest.main(FunkyMethodTest.java:5)*
```

Answer (score 3):

Java considers the type of ternary expression to be `boolean`. The compiler treats `null` as `Boolean`, i.e. the result of applying a boxing conversion to the primitive type of `boolean`.

Here is the relevant portion of the language specification:

> **15.25** The type of a conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type `T`, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to `T`, then the type of the conditional expression is `T`.

Language specification states that the boxing/unboxing conversion is applied when necessary to the operand chosen by the condition of the expression. That is what triggers the exception when the code tries to unbox a `boolean` from `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your ternary determines the operand type, in this case primitive `boolean`.

```
return a + b == 2 ? true : null;
```

Note that you can (syntactically) cast a `null` (which is technically of the NullType) to a `boolean`, however it results in a `NullPointerException`. Thus, while the code compiles, if `a + b` is not equal to `2` you get a `NullPointerException`. As for why it is syntactically legal, consider

```
return a + b == 2 ? true : Boolean.FALSE;
```

Note that `Boolean.FALSE` is a `Boolean`, and autounboxing means this code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This `return a + b == 2 ? true : (Boolean) x;` is what actually happens, though you can't write that actually, since the compiler will complain. But you could write:

```
private static boolean whyIsThisPossible(int a, int b) {
    Boolean x = null;
    if (a == b) {
        x = false;
    }
    return a + b == 2 ? true : (Boolean) x;
}
```